# Factoring a polynomial over a GF

Tags: aes, finite-field

I have the following question:

> What polynomial, when factored over the field $GF (2^8)$ based on the irreducible polynomial that is used in Rijndael, will factor into all the polynomials in the field?

As I understand it, the polynomial should be an irreducible polynomial and this polynomial must factor all the polynomials. How can I get this polynomial? What steps should I follow?

Comment: I closed this question as even after one month, it is not clear what you actually want to know. Feel free to edit it and comment if you want to have it reopened.

Answer (score 3):

There are several questions hidden in your question.

You'll have to distinguish between the polynomial ring $\mathbb Z_2[X]$, and the factor field $GF(2^8) = \mathbb Z_2[X]/F$ (where $F$ is any irreductible polynomial of degree 8).

In $\mathbb Z_2[X]$, the only polynomial which **is a factor of all others** is the trivial polynomial $1$. (In general, in a (unitary) ring the set of elements with this property are called *units*, and this ring has just the trivial unit one.)

In $GF(2^8)$ (like in any field), every non-zero element is a unit and thus a factor of every other element, but we normally don't call them "polynomials".

But the original question actually asks something else:

> What polynomial when factored over the field $GF (2^8)$ based on the irreducible polynomial that is used in Rijndael will factor into all the polynomials in the field?

The expression "factors into" can be understood as "is a multiple of" ... and "when factored over $GF(2^8)$" could be understood as "when seen as a polynomial with coefficients in $GF(2^8)$ (i.e. an element of $GF(2^8)[X]$, and then factored (into its prime divisors)". But then the expression "into all the polynomials in the field" makes no sense, as a field element is either $0$ (which is not a factor other than for itself) or a unit (which is a factor for everything), and you likely don't want $0$ as the result.

Quite likely the original question was something else, but I have no idea, what.

Answer (score 1):

Even after revision, this question makes litle sense.  The OP wants a *polynomial*  with the property that

> ... this polynomial must factor all the polynomials

or possibly

> ... will factor into all the polynomials in the field

With regard to the first, a polynomial is not an operator
or algorithm that can be used to *factor* a polynomial (or decide that
the polynomial is irreducible) and so perhaps the word
*into* was inadvertently omitted, and this question 
was supposed to be identical to the second.

With regard to the second, it is worth noting that there
are no polynomials **in** the field GF$(2^8)$
except in the sense that
all the field elements can be expressed as polynomials
of degree $7$ or less with binary coefficients.  There 
are $2^8$ such polynomials ranging from $0$ or
$0+0x+0x^2+\cdots+0x^7$ to $1+1x+1x^2+\cdots+1x^7$, and
if *factor into* means a **divisor of**, then the *only
polynomial* that  is a divisor of all these $2^8$ polynomials
is $1$, the constant polynomial.

Other possibilities might be the question

> What *binary* polynomials factor into 
>   a product of monic linear polynomials over GF$(2^8)$?

Here, monic linear polynomial means $(x-\alpha_i)$
where $\alpha_i \in \text{GF}(2^8)$.
One answer would be

> All the irreducible binary polynomials of degrees $1, 2, 4$, and $8$
>   factor into products of linear polynomials over GF$(2^8)$.

Some people would say that GF$(2^8)$ is the *splitting field*
of irreducible binary polynomials of degree $8$. 
More generally, any
polynomial that is a product of any number of these irreducible
polynomials (including repeats so that $[f(x)]^i[g(x]^j[h(x)]^k\cdots$
is allowed) will also factor into a product
of linear polynomials over GF$(2^8)$
but might have roots with multiplicity greater than $1$.